Removing code duplication between const and non-const functions that return std::span?
If I have const and non-const versions of a function that returns a span:
class Foo {
public:
    std::span<int> myFunc() {
        auto begin{vec.begin()};
        auto end{vec.end()};
        
        // Do some work that modifies begin and end.
        
        return {begin, end};
    }

    std::span<const int> myFunc() const {
        // Same as above
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3};
};

Is there any way to avoid duplicating the function bodies?
I tried the const_cast approach, but got stuck on trying to cast the std::span return value.

const_cast method is fine as long as the returned value will not violate constness.
Conversion from span<T> to span<const T> is possible but not the other way  around.
std::span<const int> Foo::myFunc() const
{
    return const_cast<Foo*>(this)->myFunc();
}


Quoting from an answer to duplicate:

NOTE: It is important that you do NOT put the logic in the non-const function and have the const-function call the non-const function -- it may result in undefined behavior. The reason is that a constant class instance gets cast as a non-constant instance. The non-const member function may accidentally modify the class, which the C++ standard states will result in undefined behavior.

Therefore, you are advised to do the following.
std::span<int> Foo::myFunc()
{
    std::span<const int> const_span = static_cast<const Foo*>(this)->myFunc();
    return std::span<int>(const_cast<int*>(const_span.data()), const_span.size());;
}


Isn't the edited guidance conflicting with the original answer? Should the original answer be removed?

@Archduke If you are sure you are not violating const correctness, the first answer is valid as well. The second answer is the best practice to prevent such issues in general.
